# Asp.Net core 3.0 The path in 'value' must start with '/'

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I couldn't find the call stack for this problem, looks like everything is fine with the controller, but it has a problem with the "asp-href-include".

Here is the exception:

```
ArgumentException: The path in 'value' must start with '/'. (Parameter 'value')
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString..ctor(string value)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets.StaticWebAssetsFileProvider.StartsWithBasePath(string subpath, out PathString rest)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets.StaticWebAssetsFileProvider.GetDirectoryContents(string subpath)
Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Composite.CompositeDirectoryContents.EnsureDirectoriesAreInitialized()
Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Composite.CompositeDirectoryContents.EnsureFilesAreInitialized()
Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Composite.CompositeDirectoryContents.GetEnumerator()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.FileProviderGlobbingDirectory.EnumerateFileSystemInfos()+MoveNext()
System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.InsertRange(int index, IEnumerable<T> collection)
System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.Internal.MatcherContext.Match(DirectoryInfoBase directory, string parentRelativePath)
Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.Internal.MatcherContext.Match(DirectoryInfoBase directory, string parentRelativePath)
Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.Internal.MatcherContext.Execute()
Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.Matcher.Execute(DirectoryInfoBase directoryInfo)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.GlobbingUrlBuilder.FindFiles(Matcher matcher)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.GlobbingUrlBuilder.ExpandGlobbedUrl(string include, string exclude)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.GlobbingUrlBuilder.BuildUrlList(string staticUrl, string includePattern, string excludePattern)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.LinkTagHelper.BuildGlobbedLinkTags(TagHelperAttributeList attributes, TagHelperContent builder)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.LinkTagHelper.Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.RunAsync(TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext)
AspNetCore.Views_Shared__Layout.<ExecuteAsync>b__17_0() in _Layout.cshtml
-
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>bizz - @ViewData["Title"]</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
    <meta content="" name="description" />
    <meta content="" name="author" />
    <link asp-href-include="~/bundle/metronic-mandatory.min.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true" /> <-- this line is highlighted red
    <link asp-href-include="~/bizz/style/common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true" />
    @RenderSection("style", false)
    <script asp-src-include="~/bundle/metronic-mandatory.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script asp-src-include="~/bundle/common.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script asp-src-include="~/bundle/jquery-validation.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync()
AspNetCore.Views_Shared__Layout.ExecuteAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderLayoutAsync(ViewContext context, ViewBufferTextWriter bodyWriter)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

the code:

```cs
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>bizz- @ViewData["Title"]</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
    <meta content="" name="description" />
    <meta content="" name="author" />
    <link asp-href-include="~/bundle/metronic-mandatory.min.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link asp-href-include="~/bizz/style/common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true" />
    @RenderSection("style", false)

    <script asp-src-include="~/bundle/metronic-mandatory.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script asp-src-include="~/bundle/common.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script asp-src-include="~/bundle/jquery-validation.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @RenderSection("script", false)
... other code
```

the controller (if needed)

```cs
public ViewResult Index()
        {


            return View();
        }
```

EDIT:
Maybe I forgot to mention this html is inside _Layout.cshtml. Does it have anything to do with the problem? Also, I whatever I write in it, it gets restored to how it was.

EDIT2: I have edited my code according to one of the comments. 
The error remains to be the same.
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaZRe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and I think it is a .NET Core 3 issue. Check the github issue here -
In 3.0, when using the asp-src-includes tag helper inside of a Scripts section to include a javascript file, a 500 error is generated. This tag helper worked just fine in 2.2.

[Tag Helper asp-src-include Not Functional in Core 3.0 #14642](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14642)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Any idea when this will get fixed?

Comment: The GitHub issue thread said Preview 3, which will have a code locked down time frame around first week of December, so don't expect the fix to be out until at least middle of December 2019, I would think. This is the milestones - https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/milestones

Answer (score 2):

You will need to resolve the content URL using `@Url.Content` e.g.:

```
<script asp-src-include="@Url.Content("~/bundle/metronic-mandatory.min.js")" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

Comment: Alright, I have tried your comment, I edited the code for the first line to check if it works. But apparently it just disappears? It's really hard to explain, so I just created a video for it. Sorry for mobile video:
[link](https://youtu.be/nQF3Pgb-SNE)

Comment: @JeremyGyovai-Rafa Did you try a clean and rebuild. Even if when the resource doesn't exist then the `~` should be expanded out?

Comment: Question edited according to your comment. The issue remains the same even with the edited code.